# Flutter | Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I'm trying to run flutter app, before adding major features I tried to test the app after removing the counter and adding `AppBar` but it shows this error in the console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on INE LX2 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I removed the `gradle` folder from `my_project > android` directory and tried to run again but same error appeared again

here is my code that I'm trying to run:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MainContent.dart';
void main() =>runApp(FFI());


class FFI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MainContent(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the `MainContent()` class in different `dart file` :

```
class MainContent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainContentState createState() => _MainContentState();
}

class _MainContentState extends State<MainContent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const<BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "one",
              icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code_scanner_rounded,)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: "two",
              icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: "three",
              icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help, thank you

EDIT:

I tried to run previous flutter projects and faced the same error although it used to work fine

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens on Android builds when you try to run an old Flutter project that you haven't touched for a while. What you can do here is update all the plugins that you're using and rebuild the Android build.

Run `flutter pub upgrade` to upgrade the plugins in the project. Then try running the project. If the issue persists, run `flutter doctor` to check for any errors.

If you'd like to regenerate the entire Android build, you can delete the `/android` folder, then run `flutter create --platforms=android [PROJECT_PATH]` - this should generate the Android project from the Flutter code.